# Implement schema registry with a basic auth

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-platform

I want to implement schema registry with basic auth credential. For this reason I googled and found [this link](https://docs.confluent.io/current/schema-registry/security/index.html) which is very confusing for me. For example, it stated the use following settings  configure Schema Registry to require authentication:

```
authentication.method=BASIC
authentication.roles=<user-role1>,<user-role2>,...
authentication.realm=<section-in-jaas_config.file>
```

where should i add these lines?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration that is described in the page that you linked to (specifically, the section titled [Configuring the REST API for Basic HTTP Authentication](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/security/index.html#configuring-the-rest-api-for-basic-http-authentication)) works for me, *but* only after updating to Confluent 6.2.1.

*I don't know how to check which version my old one was, but it was from March, 2020. With this version the schema registry would allow unauthenticated requests, despite the configuration being in place. This is strange since the referenced documentation already existed back then, so that version must have supported it. The only explanation I can offer is that said version must have had a bug which made it somehow not recognize my configuration.*

To answer your question, the `authentication....=` lines must be added to the schema registry config file which you include in the command line when you run *schema-registry-start.bat*. Ensure the `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_OPTS` environment variable is set to point to your *jaas.properties* file. This file in turn specifies the path to your password file (note this path is relative to the processes' working directory). Really just follow the steps outlined in the documentation, and it should work .

Answer (score -1):

I think basic auth is only going to work when you put for example nginx in front of it and proxy the request towards the schema registry. Then use nginx to setup the basic auth.

The page you mention has an **Authentication** chapter but that's only from the schema registry towards the brokers.

To protect the schema registry endpoint Confluent offers a paid plugin:

> **Schema Registry Security Plugin**
>   This is a commercial component of Confluent Platform.

I'm looking for a solution as well, hence landed on your question.
You could also use a firewall to limit the IPs that can access the schema registry ports. In addition, your producers and consumers need to be able to handle the basic auth mechanism, all in all, not perfect. Not sure why the schema registry can't use the zookeeper SCRAM users for example, would be the easiest way to go.

EDIT:
In addition, you could also use an url like this:

```
https://username:password@registry.example.com/
```

Not ideal, but it works I guess...

Comment: The Confluent schema registry does implement basic HTTP authentication (on the client-side) and this configuration is described on the referenced page (see https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/security/index.html#configuring-the-rest-api-for-basic-http-authentication).

I did have to upgrade to the latest version (see my answer), though my previous version was more recent than said documentation.